# pig installation in windows using cygwin

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, apache-pig, hadoop-plugins, cygpath

I am using cygwin in windows xp to install pig-0.11.1.I extracted and placed my pig_home folder in user directory of cygwin.When i try commanding in prompt ./pig help, it shows me the following error.

which: no hadoop in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin:/home/sunil/pig-0.11.1/bin)
cygpath: cannot create short name of C:\cygwin\home\sunil\pig-0.11.1\logs
Cannot locate pig.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

Can i get some help regarding this.Thanks in advance.

Regards,
 john

Comment: Try with the steps described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23577268/1282533, this will help for PIG installation in a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Make sure your PIG_HOME variable is set correctly.
- There should be a pig.jar (as well as a pig-withouthadoop.jar) file in your pig-0.11.1 directory. Make sure they live where $PIG_HOME is pointing. These files might have the name pig-0.11.1.jar or pig-0.11.1-withouthadoop.jar.
- If you're still having problems, cygwin is fussy with the pig-x.y.z.jar filenames. Rename these to just "pig.jar" or "pig-withouthadoop.jar" and try again.

Good luck!